# Mongodb query explain opterationTime meaning?

Tags: mongodb, performance, shell, explain

We want to find the performance difference between the regular string comparison vs regex comparison. need the further understanding/explanation about the 'operationTime'.

any one can explain the meaning of 'operationTime'?

"operationTime" : Timestamp(1573768915, 16291) // it takes 16.291ms ?
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1573768904, 15024) // it takes 15.024ms ?

````
db.getCollection("customer").find({accountId: "abcdefg"}).explain()
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
        "namespace" : "myserver.customer", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "accountId" : {
                "$eq" : "abcdefg"
            }
        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "indexName" : "accountId_partnerId", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                }, 
                "isUnique" : true, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : true, 
                "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                "direction" : "forward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "accountId" : [
                        "[\"abcdefg\", \"abcdefg\"]"
                    ], 
                    "partnerId" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongodb-delta-02", 
        "port" : 27017.0, 
        "version" : "3.6.10", 
        "gitVersion" : "3e3ab85bfb98875af3bc6e74eeb945b0719f69c8"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0, 
    **"operationTime" : Timestamp(1573768915, 16291),**
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1573768915, 16291)
    }
}

db.getCollection("customer").find({accountId: /^abcdefg$/}).explain()
{ 
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1.0, 
        "namespace" : "myserver-customer", 
        "indexFilterSet" : false, 
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "accountId" : {
                "$regex" : "^abcdefg$"
            }
        }, 
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "filter" : {
                    "accountId" : {
                        "$regex" : "^abcdefg$"
                    }
                },
                "indexName" : "accountId_partnerId", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "isUnique" : true, 
                "isSparse" : false, 
                "isPartial" : true, 
                "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
                "direction" : "forward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "accountId" : [
                        "[\"abcdefg\", \"abcdef:\")", 
                        "[/^abcdefg$/, /^abcdefg$/]"
                    ], 
                    "partnerId" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    }, 
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongodb-delta-02", 
        "port" : 27017.0, 
        "version" : "3.6.10", 
        "gitVersion" : "3e3ab85bfb98875af3bc6e74eeb945b0719f69c8"
    }, 
    "ok" : 1.0, 
    **"operationTime" : Timestamp(1573768904, 15024),**
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1573768904, 15024)
    }
}```
````

Comment: "We want to find the performance difference between the regular string comparison vs regex comparison...": You need to run the `explain` with "executionStats" mode to get the _query plan + execution statistics_. _Execution statistics_ will show the usage of indexes and the time to execute the query details: [explain("executionStats") output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html#executionstats).

Comment: Thanks, Prasad,  we did try with .explain('executionStats').  Mongodb V3.6.10 looks not support that parameter 'executionStats'.

Comment: Yes, it does support the "executionStats" mode. Here is the link to MongoDB documentation (v3.6) for [explain verbosity modes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#explain-method-verbosity).. _Also_, the query planner's analysis shows the [executionStats (for v3.6)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/).

Comment: Yes. it does. thanks. I did go through the two url links in your post. those do not answer my question: "operationTime" : Timestamp(1573768915, 16291) // it takes 16.291ms ?

Answer (score -1):

Please do read the response section. The entire description will help you to understand the "Response Field".

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/index.html#response

Comment: Thanks, Bru, for the reference.

Comment: "The logical time of the performed operation", it's in "db.runCommand()".  for our usecase, Timestamp(1573768915, 16291) is the logical time of "....explain()",  or the one for ".find({accountId: "abcdefg"})" ?  another question is what the meaning of "Timestamp(1573768915, 16291)",  "1573768915"=?, "16291"=?